# How can I animate the background color of a table using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, animation, html-table, effect

I have a table with some styling. It's like:

```
<table class="table_design" id="cart">
   <tr>
       <td>something</td>
       <td>something else</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

I tried:

```
$("#cart").animate({backgroundColor: '#FF0000'}, 'slow');
```

and

```
$("#cart").effect("highlight", {}, 3000);
```

But, They both are not working.

What do you recommend?

Comment: You may also want to add a hover event or click event depending on your functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) into your project and the `.animate` method [will animate colors](http://jqueryui.com/demos/animate/).

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.20/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

You can get it from a CDN hosted by either [Microsoft](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/cdn.ashx) or [Google](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide).

Comment: Perhaps for clarity you should also mention that the code doesn't change.

Comment: OK, It worked. I also able to change the background to the old color after the animation using the same function twice.

Answer (score 1):

You need jquery-ui to do animation on background colour. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2qTW8/)